# Page lost from Google Search

Tags: seo, google-search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to diagnose a search engine ranking drop?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/16941/how-to-diagnose-a-search-engine-ranking-drop)

I wrote this guide on how to root HTC Desire, http://techspalace.blogspot.com/2011/10/perm-root-htc-desire-gingerbread-233.html .

I had been getting decent visit from Google Search and also the page use to rank in top 3 for queries relating to "perm root htc desire gingerbread".

But from last few days the comments on the post nearly stopped. Upon investigating I found that Google doesn't show my page any more for such queries.

What could have gone wrong? Can anyone please shed some light onto this.

Answer (score 2):

I searched and your URL was on the second page of results. So you haven't been *removed* at all, you are simply ranking lower. This could be any number of reasons, including:

- If you were the only page directly matching your term, you would rank high. Now other more popular sites made similar pages they outrank you.
- A page that linked to you no longer does.
- More pages are linking to competing pages who now rank above you.
- Your competitors did some other SEO (e.g. better page titles or headings).
- Your site could have become significantly slower than other pages (very unlikely since it loads fine for me, and page speed only affects 1/1000 sites)