# High Google page ranking lost overnight

Tags: seo, google-search-console, google-search, subdomain

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to diagnose a search engine ranking drop?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/16941/how-to-diagnose-a-search-engine-ranking-drop)

I had achieved a high ranking for a page on my site of the form:
http://domain.com/mypage.htm

Overnight the page is not even in the first 10 pages of Google, my company has effectively disappeared.

I think it is related to a limitation with my domain name hosting company, they no longer support forwarding of pages of the form:

http://domain.com/mypage.htm which previously redirected to http://www.domain.com/mypage.htm

However, now it will only redirect to the root page, i.e. http://www.domain.com

I am guessing that this explains why my page http://domain.com/mypage.htm is no longer visible to Google.

The solution would seem to be to set www.domain.com as my preferred domain in Google with Web Master Tools. However, two weeks after doing this my site is not appearing anywhere in Google.  I have also resubmitted my crawl maps (which orignially explicity used the www subdomain) and sent for site reconsideration but no luck.

Any suggestion for tools to diagnose or a solution?  Or is it just a question of waiting and hoping?

Comment: Are you sure that Google (for some reason like cloacking) has not banned your page?

Comment: The problem might be that links to the page, which are one of the things that increase your ranking, go to www.domain.com/maypage.htm. I would switch hosting company.