# Why are the rankings of my webpage down on single phrase?

Tags: links, search-results, sitelinks

One webpage used to rank better in search.  It had more visibility and had site links.

But in the last few days, it is down three position on one phase, and it no longer has site links.

What caused this to happen?

Comment: I am having a hard time trying to understand what you are actually asking? Sitelinks are generally only shown in Google search results if you are ranked position 1 and Google finds links on your pages which it thinks might be a good match. If you lose position 1 on the search results page (for any given keyword) your sitelinks are not displayed either.

Comment: What you have asked is a frequently asked question.   Please see: [How to diagnose a search engine ranking drop?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/16941/14543)