# Can preventing directory listings in WordPress upload folders cause Google ranking drops when they cause 403 errors in Webmaster Tools?

Tags: wordpress, google-ranking, 403-forbidden

I recently moved to a new host that blocks crawling to my uploads folders but (hopefully) allows the files in the folder to be crawled.

I now show many 403 errors for each folder in the uploads folder in my Webmaster Tools. For example, http://www.rewardcharts4kids.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/ shows a 403 error.

For example, I can access this file: http://www.rewardcharts4kids.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/lunch-box-notes.jpg but I cannot access the folder it is in.

My rankings went down after I moved to this host and I am wondering if:

1. this could be the reason.
2. is this how files/folders are supposed to be set up?

Comment: I can't imagine that the folders would have any impact on your Google ranking.  You might find this catch all question to be informative: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/16941/how-to-diagnose-a-search-engine-ranking-drop

Answer (score 1):

Your website deliberately does not want anybody to browse directories - you have to navigate from one specific webpage to another using the hyperlinks in those webpages. 
This is true for most websites on the Internet - their web server has `Allow directory browsing` set OFF.

In nutshell, You don't have permission to access `/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/` on this server.

Comment: If this is so common then why does Google send me messages twice a week about this? Makes me think that there is some problem here.

Comment: Have you changed any directory privileges?? Have you checked the current permission levels?

Comment: Google warns you when the directly is completely blocked, not just blocked from listing all files but disallowed...

Comment: The crawl errors that are reported in webmaster tools should not be hurting your site as long as the errors aren't on pages you expect to be ranking: https://plus.google.com/+JohnMueller/posts/RMjFPCSs5fm