# Pages uploaded to WordPress as media are causing mobile usability errors in Google Search Console

Tags: seo, google-search-console, wordpress, web-crawlers, robots.txt

the new search console is pointing out usability errors on mobile devices on WordPress upload pages, that is, pages where I can not change font size, viewport window and things like that, how do I solve it, or what to do with that Google does not take those pages into account.

The errors are these:

> - Text too small for reading
> - The preview window is not set
> - The clickable elements are very close

Comment: See also: [Can preventing directory listings in WordPress upload folders cause Google ranking drops when they cause 403 errors in Webmaster Tools?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/51998/can-preventing-directory-listings-in-wordpress-upload-folders-cause-google-ranki)

Answer (score 0):

You can deny googlebot to index that pages.

Here is example of robots.txt I found, that optimizes wp for search bots:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /wp-admin
Disallow: /wp-includes
Disallow: /wp-content/plugins
Disallow: /wp-json/
Disallow: /wp-login.php
Disallow: /wp-register.php
Disallow: */embed
Disallow: */feed
Disallow: /cgi-bin
Disallow: *?s=
Allow: /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
```