# Search ranking for important keywords has gone down drastically

Tags: google-search-console, google-search, traffic, ranking, google-ranking

Firstly, we are a small entrepreneurial team of 3 persons and I am more like an amateur webmaster of the company's website as we cannot really afford a technical guy/department right now.

A few weeks earlier, our website traffic and rankings for most keywords decreased overnight. I did a lot of reading henceforth and learned about Penguin 2.1 which people said is the reason for the drop. Something like this had never happened before. Now, I have gone through the entire Google webmaster help section. It says there that if a manual penalty is taken against us, we would notice a message in Manual Actions page. So far, we haven't received any notice from Google for web spam.

Some SEO guys I contacted said they found spam links in our backlink profile. I do believe I had mistakenly purchased a cheap link/SEO scheme when I was yet very new to SEO. This was more than a year back but since then we have been legitimate. Moreover, how do I find out which is a spam link and which is not? Our content is all original, refreshing and the best you will find in our niche. We also have a blog but on a different domain (wordpress.com) from where we send out anchored links to our business website. Is this a good thing to do?

Now, how should we proceed and recover our traffic/rankings. I tried searching in webmasters for a way to reach google and ask them why the traffic has decreased suddenly, but I couldn't find a contact form or something.

Can someone please go through our website and help in making things more clear regarding the reason for the drop, along with a solution.

Will really appreciate this as I can't get to figure this out and its taking a lot of time.

Vaivhav

Comment: This site does not offer individual site reviews.  Please see http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/16941/how-to-diagnose-a-search-engine-ranking-drop for information about how to diagnose the problem yourself.

Comment: Hi. Forwarding us to a question which was asked in 2011 doesn't really solve our problem. This is 2013 and many things have changed since then. If not a individual site review, can someone atleast give an idea about this. This is a poor response I don't expect from a StackExchange Mod.

Comment: I'm sorry, but the policy against site reviews is not mine alone.  If you have a suggestion about how to handle this type of question better, please raise it on the meta site: http://meta.webmasters.stackexchange.com/