# Big reduction: indexed pages, structured data items, pages crawled

Tags: google, google-search

While it doesn't appear like we have more errors or specific problems, there has been a big reduction since mid-Feburary in number of pages crawled, number of structured data items, number of indexed pages. 
As the website uses responsive design and offers exactly the same urls/data for mobile and desktop, we shouldn't be affected by the Mobile-first switch. 
Previously the numbers were growing slowly, but since mid-February we've lost around 200k structured items, 6M indexed pages and around 3M crawled pages per day.

Are there any other Google changes that could affect the stats in the past 2 months? I've looked through the discussions on this forum, but haven't found anything that could be relevant to our case.

Comment: See: [How to diagnose a search engine ranking drop?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/16941/how-to-diagnose-a-search-engine-ranking-drop)   I'm not sure its exact duplicate but the answers there should help you.

Comment: You should check out the threads on Webmasterworld: [Google Updates and SERP Changes - May 2018](https://www.webmasterworld.com/google/4899136.htm)  They track updates from Google better than we do here.

Comment: Thanks but none of it is helpful unfortunately. I've checked everything that's linked already, and posted on webmasterworld as well. As I wrote, none of the usual factors nor Google updates seem to affect us.