# Moves in serps after changing title and description - how long does it take?

Tags: search-results, title

I have a question. Some time ago I have changed my title and description of my site. The changes were visible in google after a short while - day or two (new titles visible). But now, after about two weeks my ranks dropped suddenly for most of my terms. And now I am wondering if it can be caused because of changes I made (titles/description) or it is rather something else?

My site has several years and it had stable ranks since 1 year+. It has good metrics and rather "good, quality" backlink profile. What is your opinion? Thank you in advance for any advices.

Comment: The part of your question about "could it be something else" is answered here: [How to diagnose a search engine ranking drop?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/16941/how-to-diagnose-a-search-engine-ranking-drop)

Comment: The part about "what is your opinion" is not a good fit here because answers here are expected to be fact based, not opinions.