# Why does my website keep sinking back after a rise in Google rank?

Tags: seo, search-results, google-ranking

I have an awful time trying to rank my website on Google. Every so often, (usually corresponding with a Google update), it will rise in rank. But then, after a short period, it will always sinks back down the SERPs.

Sometimes this sinking will happen slowly (as it is doing currently after the Sep 2022 core update - which made the site rise to a high of position 16) and sometimes it will be sudden - for example a 10 place drop overnight).

What could be the reason for this yo-yo'ing?

Comment: related: [How to diagnose a search engine ranking drop?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/16941/how-to-diagnose-a-search-engine-ranking-drop)

Comment: Interesting (to me at least...) point: Monday it was in position 23 all day; Tuesday it was in position 24 all day; this morning it was in position 25 and just now, it has jumped up to position 18. More yo-yo'ing. :-(

Comment: Is this happening in tandem for all keywords that you are monitoring, are you only looking at a single keyword?

Comment: "javascript charts" is the search that I'm concerned about. 15th for the search "html5 charts" but the former is a far more popular search and so it's the one I'm concerned with.

Comment: Interestingly (ish), if I do a search for "javascript charts" whilst I'm logged in to my Google account I get a little panel showing clicks/impressions/avg position and the avg position figure is going up. It jumped up 2.0 this morning to 22.6

Comment: And this morning... back to 25 :-( From something I remember John Mooler saying - this smells like two of Google's algorithms disagreeing. Determining the one that dislikes my site and why though... that's quite a task.

Comment: I'm currently considering changing the example charts from real canvas/svg charts to pictures (why? I read that there's a delay in JavaScript rendering so Google may be looking at the pages without the charts being there)