# SERP Dropping majorly - Lighthouse SEO Questionmark

Tags: seo, google-pagespeed, lighthouse

Before last week when I checked my website in PageSpeed Insights I had a SEO score of about 92. All of a sudden there is a question mark at the SEO score and my Google ranking is dropping from 5th to 70+. First I thought this had something to do with the update of 27 march. My store runs on Shopify. The PageSpeed insight I did is for `/products/whitening-strips`

Does anyone have any explanation for this and what could I do? Many thanks in advance!

PageSpeed Insights score overview:

[image: PageSpeed Insights score overview]

SEO Score:

[image: SEO Score]

SERP dropping majorly:

[image: SERP dropping majorly]

Restoring a backup of my theme (before enabling lazy loading and removing some scripts) did not make any difference.

Comment: Changing something isnt going to have an instant effect. If the drop was related to your changes, then it took a fortnight. Also, I  don't see how anyone can answer the question without more information.

Comment: General advice for similar situations: [How to diagnose a search engine ranking drop?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/16941/how-to-diagnose-a-search-engine-ranking-drop)