# Google is showing many results for a site: search for my old redirected site, is that the cause of my SEO problems?

Tags: 301-redirect

I have 301 redirect on my old site to new one but Google constantly indexing content from new website on my old website. [google search old site](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=site%3Aordaz.se)

I had very good progress, but maybe the duplicate content in the Google search crashed it. I am very disappointed and I don't know where the mistake is..

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because the site: search is a special case that bends over backwards to try and provide what you asked for, which is pages from a specific domain.

If you check the cache for each URL listed, you will see it states your new URLs as the source/canonical. (triple dot menu, then cache button at the bottom).

Comment: I understand but I still can find old site in search results with particular keywords and content from new site..

Answer (score 0):

After implementing the redirect, it will take Google up to a year to index all the content on the new site rather than the old site.

The proper way to check how much is indexed from your old site is to add the old site to Google Search Console and view the indexing stats.  As Tony says in their answer, `site:` searches are not a reliable way to see what is indexed.

Your ranking and traffic problems are unlikely to be caused by duplicate content.  Google does not usually penalize for duplicate content.  It simply picks one of the two duplicated URLs to index.  In any case, Google isn't likely to see redirect URL as duplicating their destinations.  See [What is duplicate content and how can I avoid being penalized for it on my site?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/35652/what-is-duplicate-content-and-how-can-i-avoid-being-penalized-for-it-on-my-site)

Comment: https://prnt.sc/DeSPgT0bkVCe I have had constant traffic on the old site for more than 2-3 years, redirected to a new domain, updated additional content, it started well for 1 year and then out of the blue this kind of dropdown

Comment: See [How to diagnose a search engine ranking drop?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/16941/how-to-diagnose-a-search-engine-ranking-drop) for advice about that.

Comment: Unfortunately, I did not find the answer. The only thing that comes to my mind that led to a drop in traffic is bad content, that google started valuing it differently, because it consists of a collection of a couple of public sources that are combined. And that redirect, which I immediately suspected because I didn't check it before and I saw tens of thousands of duplicate content.

Comment: How long ago did you redirect your site?   Did you use Google's change of address tool at the time?

Comment: At least one year. I didn't use Google's change of address tool. I have a different structure after the redirect, didn't know I can use it in that case also.

Comment: As long as you redirect from the old structure to the new on the new site, it should be possible to use change of address.

Comment: Since you did the redirect more than a year ago, it is unlikely to have anything to do with your current ranking problems.   Ranking problems from domain changes could happen within the first couple months of the redirect.

Comment: It looks like all the old URLs redirect to the home page of the new site. Is that the case? They should all redirect to the specific page on the new site.