# Why my two highly ranked pages disapeared from SERP?

Tags: seo

This question isnt about **ranking drop**,its about **pages disaper** and other questions **arent similar at all**.Before 15 days my first highly ranked page for Windows installation **vanished(not dropped)** from SERP,before 7 days i noticed than second one for SEO optimization also vanished- **not dropped in ranking,completely vanished**.**I checked to the last google page and my pages are nowhere to be found**.I read a lot about this kind of issue and cant find any reasonable explanation,by the way,in google search console there is no actions against my domain and pages are still indexed.
Am i doing something wrong or this is huge google bug?Both pages are with quality content written as clean website(only HTML,CSS and JavaScript) with very good performances.Pages are 2 years old.

Thanks in advance,
Goran ,
Novi Sad,
Serbia.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to diagnose a search engine ranking drop?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/16941/how-to-diagnose-a-search-engine-ranking-drop)

Comment: @Trebor Its not a drop,its vanishing buddy.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why aren't search engines indexing my content?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/43350/why-arent-search-engines-indexing-my-content)

Comment: @StephenOstermiller No.

Comment: I'm not sure if there is any advice we can give other than what is listed there though.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller They return second one page in SERP today,first one still missing.