# Just after 1 month, impression dropped to ~0. After enhancing the content, why and what to do next?

Tags: google-search, spam, content, penalty, impressions

My website is a listing website that lists AI tools over the internet.

[image: impression diagram]

After submitting my new website to Google Search Console, the initial impression remained around 400 for about a month. However, it suddenly dropped to nearly 0 and has remained at that level for the past 23 days.

I think the issue might be the spam score or the content quality. It's strange because some competitors with similar or worse content show up in Google search results.
Can you think of any other reason?

Anyway, I much enhanced contents of pages that I was suspicious of being recognized as spam. I'm now pretty sure that I don't display any spam.

Now, what next?

1. Should I request Google to re-index my pages?
2. Or change the domain and submit the website again? (because I spent money and time to improve the content, so it maybe less risky).

What do you recommend?

**My question is different that [How to diagnose a search engine ranking drop?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/16941/how-to-diagnose-a-search-engine-ranking-drop)** because: 1- My website is not an established one. It's new. 2- Impression has not dropped by 90%, but has dropped to Zero. 3- It's 2024, not 2011 (It's clear that things have changed).